# Using functions from JAR file

Tags: java, jar

Suppose I have a Project Calculator. It has one java class DMAS.java in package org.math; DMAS.java contains 4 basic mathematical operations (implemented as java functions) add,subtract,multiply,divide. Each takes two arguments and returns the required result. I have built a JAR for this project, let's name it calculator.JAR .

Now let's switch to another project. Let's name it AdvancedCalculator. I include calculator.JAR in build path of AdvancedCalculator project. How do I call functions defined in class DMAS.java from AdvancedCalculator project?

All Methods in DMAS.java are static.

Comment: DMAS.functionName() no need to create an object for it.

Comment: it asks me to create class org.math.DMAS; If I import org.math.DMAS; it stills asks the same thing. Am I importing incorrectly?

Comment: I think your jar is not added properly or your package structure is not proper. Type DMAS and use eclipse to find the package. if eclipse is not able to identify the class name then your jar is not added properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have created and added the JAR correctly. It is not different from the scenario where you can call these functions from a package containing DMAS.java with in your project "AdvancedCalculator"  
There are two ways:

```
import org.math.DMAS;
// with in the main function of class of "AdvancedCalculator" invoke a function like
DMAS.add(arg1,arg2);
```

Or you can use this line to invoke a function, without importing DMAS.

```
org.math.DMAS.add(arg1,arg2);
```

To check the validity of created JAR, you can Expand it from Referenced Libraries and check if DMAS.class exists and also compare the function's definition in JAR with the function call. Make sure you are interfacing correctly.

Comment: Your last paragraph gives the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You would call then exactly as if they weren't in a jar-file but in the same project.

```
org.math.DMAS.add(3,4);
```

Comment: it asks me to create class org.math.DMAS; 
If I import org.math.DMAS; it stills asks the same thing. Am I importing incorrectly?

Comment: Make sure you add it to the class path in bothe the `javac` and the `java` command if you are not using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

```
 import DMAS.jar //you have to add jar file in to your advanced project lib once added 
 then you can use all the methods of that jar file .eg

   DMAS.add(arg1,arg2)
```

Comment: i hope you know how to add jar file in to library.